# How to publish/produce datapoints to an API from R?

Tags: r, api, rest, swagger, plumber

I have these datapoints from a model I developed and I would like to publish an API using R. I've explored the plumber library within R from this [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCXYzN0HbwA&t=1274s&ab_channel=SaltLakeCityRUsersGroup) video. However, the tutorials I have encountered tend to share very minimal and uncomplicated datasets (not that mine is anything crazy). I just haven't been able to fully understand the syntax of plumber or how the functions work.

**Here is an example/shortend verison of my data and what I would like to produce as an API:**

| ID | BRANCH_ZIP_1 | STR_ZIP_1 | CONFIGURATION | PREDICTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60804002 | 3 | 3 | 33 | 7 |

Additionally, I have multiple rows of this data so would be great if there is a functional solution rather than a static solution with this one example I shared.

I understand I will need to host it somewhere, can swagger or digital ocean take care of that?

**I converted my data frame to JSON as follows**

```
f <- toJSON(predictions)
```

**f returns:**

```
[{"MVNDR_NBR":60804002,"MVNDR_NM":"S/O WEYERHAEUSER NR CO.","BRANCH_ZIP_1":3,"STR_ZIP_1":3,"CONFIGURATION":"33","BRANCH_REGION":"SOUTHEAST","STR_REGION":"0024","PREDICTED_LEAD_TIME":19,"WEEK_TO_APPLY":"202233"},

{"MVNDR_NBR":60804002,"MVNDR_NM":"S/O WEYERHAEUSER NR CO.","BRANCH_ZIP_1":3,"STR_ZIP_1":3,"CONFIGURATION":"33","BRANCH_REGION":"SOUTHEAST","STR_REGION":"0047","PREDICTED_LEAD_TIME":16,"WEEK_TO_APPLY":"202233"}]
```

How do I get this JSON blob above to return an API that provides this data. I am not understanding how to write this code in plumber with the functions required.

Comment: Plumber isn't intended to to return data specifically--it's designed to return anything. APIs commonly return data in JSON format, so write function that returns your data as JSON (use `jsonlite::toJSON(your_data)` at the very end), and have Plumber return that. Or write your data to a CSV file [and have plumber return that](https://www.rplumber.io/reference/include_file.html). [This blog post](https://gabrielcp.medium.com/making-apis-with-r-plumber-examples-and-tips-a36efdffc3fd) shows a simple example returning either JSON data or a CSV.

Comment: Okay, gotcha I converted my data to JSON using the function shared, I am still unsure how to host that data.

Comment: It's hard to help without understanding where your confusion is. I can copy the code from the blog post in the earlier comment and replace their function  `function(mean, sd) { data.frame(x=seq(10), letters=letters[1:10]) }` with a function that returns your data: `function() {structure(list(ID = 60804002L, BRANCH_ZIP_1 = 3L, STR_ZIP_1 = 3L, nCONFIGURATION = 33L, PREDICTION = 7L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))}`. Have you tried something like that? Get a minimal example like from the blog post working as-is, then modify it slightly?

Comment: Also, I'd encourage you to separate the question of "how do I build an API that returns this data" from the question of "how do I host an API" as they are unrelated. Build an API that works locally first. Then worry about hosting it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I will update my question with what I have at the moment.

Comment: I geniunely dont understand. I have a dataframe and converted it to a JSON object. I dont understand the plumber part at all.

Comment: It feels like you're asking for a custom tutorial (which is off-topic) on a subject that there are many tutorials on. You could make this specific and reproducible by showing us your attempt. Copy paste the code from a tutorial and try to run it. If you can't get it working, show the code you tried in your question. If you can get it working, then try to modify it to return your data instead of the data in the example. Again, if you can't get it working, ask a question showing your attempt.

Comment: I'll also say, I think my initial comment might be misleading---looking at the tutorial link I posted seems like the JSON conversion is automatic and you don't need to do it yourself.